# Why Do Some Font's Letter Spacing Vary Between Font Renders But Not Others?

Tags: fonts, gdi+, quartz-graphics, core-text, directwrite

Why is there so much variation between how font renderers treat fonts? Specifically, why is letter spacing vary with some fonts & not with others?

For example, why does "Open Sans" have near-identical letter spacing between all environments? But "Arial" letter spacing varies drastically? Does the "Arial" font have some metadata that "Open Sans" does not?

**Open Sans, 16pt**

[image]

**Arial, 16pt**

[image]

Thanks.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it has nothing to do with programming as defined in the FAQ.

Comment: @Rob, that's a fair point... i was hoping to see if i could do some normalization programatically. But first i have to understand the problem....

Comment: @Markus: one of the reasons is that it depends on how renderer treats metrics, are they adjusted after hinting or stay at design values. Also font size could mean different things on different systems.

Comment: @bunglehead Thank you for your reply. I am very interested to know the dirty details of how the renderer treats different metrics under different circumstances.